# JSX select element does not seem to auto-select (implement 'selected') on option. Am I missing something?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `<select>` tag which I use to create my own custom `<SelectField>` component as follows:

```js
export default function SelectField(props) {
  /* 
  PARAMS:
    - fieldname (String)
    - fieldID (String)
    - options (Array([Object, Object...]) [{"option_value": "option_name"}, ...])
    - init_value (String "option_value")
  */
  const generate_options = () => {
    // Function for handling SelectField options
    let element_list = [];
    element_list.push(
      <SelectOption key={0} option_value="" option_text="None" />
    );

    var count = 1;

    if (!Array.isArray(props.options)) {
      for (var [value, name] of Object.entries(props.options)) {
        element_list.push(
          <SelectOption key={count} option_value={value} option_text={name} />
        );
        count += 1;
      }
    } else {
      props.options.forEach((subject) => {
        element_list.push(subject.to_option());
      });
    }
    return element_list;
  };

  const nameToString = () => {
    // Converts props.fieldname into a properly formatted name
    if(props.fieldname.indexOf("_")){
      var full_field_name = `${props.fieldname.split("_").join(" ")}`;
      return `${full_field_name[0].toUpperCase() + full_field_name.slice(1)}`;
    };
    return `${props.fieldname[0].toUpperCase() + props.fieldname.slice(1)}`;
  };

  return (
    <div className="form-group">
      <label htmlFor={props.fieldname}>
        {nameToString()}:
      </label>
      <select
        name={`${props.fieldname}`}
        id={`${props.fieldID}`}
        className="countries"
        defaultValue={props?.init_value ? `${props.init_value}` : ""}
      >
        {generate_options()}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

(PS. Don't mind the className - it really SHOULDN'T relevant. But who knows with a beginner like me... DS). Now, I want to use that field to create a `<select>` tag for `Subjects` within my web-app (powered by Django), and I created a sub-component for it that looks like this:

```js
export function SubjectSelectField(props) {
  const [subjects, setSubjects] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getSubjects = async () => {
      let reqObj = new RequestHandler("/courses/subjects/");
      const data = await reqObj.sendRequest();
      setSubjects(
        data.map((item) => {
          return new Subject(item);
        })
      );
    };
    getSubjects();
  }, []);
  console.log({ subjects });

  return <SelectField options={subjects} {...props} />;
}
```

When rendering the page with this component, I get the following console.logs:

```js
{
    "subjects": [
        {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "Art"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Biology"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Chemistry"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Geography"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Language"
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Mathmatics"
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "name": "Physics"
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "name": "Social Studies"
        }
    ]
}
```

For reference; this is my custom `Subject` class (ES6):

```js
export class Subject {
  constructor({ id, name }) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }
  to_option() {
    return (
      <SelectOption
        key={this.id}
        option_value={this.id}
        option_text={this.name}
      />
    );
  };
}
```

And the `<SelectOption>` component:

```js
export function SelectOption(props) {
  return <option value={`${props.option_value}`} >{`${props.option_text}`}</option>;
}
```

So, the output I expect is for the `<SelectField>` to automatically assign the `selected` attribute to the option that has the value of the `<SelectField>`'s `init_value` prop.
I use the `<SelectField>` for another type of field I call `<CountrySelectField>` and that works just fine. The country I expect to be pre-selected is properly selected as per its `init_value`.

That component looks like this:

```js
export function CountrySelectField(props) {
  return (
    <SelectField
      init_value={props?.student?.country ? `${props.student.country}` : ""}
      {...props}
    />
  );
}
```

As I mentioned, if I pass a value to this component's `init_value` prop, it executes just as expected and renders with correct option having `selected` attribute set on it.

The `<SubjectSelectField>` doesn't render the way I expect - with correct `<option>` having a `selected` attribute set.

Why does it not work?

EDIT:

Changed the Subject class to a React functional component:

```js
export function Subject(props){
  const id = props.subject.id;
  const name = props.subject.name;

  console.log(id, name, props.subject);
  if(props.option){
    return(
      <SelectOption
        key={id}
        option_value={id}
        option_text={name}
      />
    );
  }
  return(
    <h1>{name} - {id}</h1>
  );
}
```

In order for other things to work, I changed these things too:

```js
export function SubjectSelectField(props) {
  // ...
  setSubjects(
        data.map((item) => {
          return <Subject subject={item} />;
        })
      );
  // ...
```

The option still won't be auto-selected.. I have other fields that works with mostly the same logic (SelectField is used in other places as well and works), but I have clearly messed something up here.

PS.
If you have time to language-police, you definitely have time to look into the question too. Don't you, @halfer? Jeez..
DS.

Comment: Any reason you’ve used a class for Subject? Native JavaScript classes aren’t able to deal with JSX unless you extend React.Component. If you add that to your class and replace to_option with render it might work. Also you’re mixing a lot of vars with lets etc, it’s best practice to use ES6 let or const.

Comment: Can you update your question to include all the relevant code? What is `SelectOption` component rendering?

Comment: @bopbopbop I will try to make the component that way later today and update you on how that works. Thanks for the tip!
@DrewReese Updated now to include the `<SelectOption>` component definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am relieved to have solved this problem on my own, and the problem was that I never implemented a check on the `SubjectSelecField` to render the `<select>` field ONLY when the `Subject`s are loaded form the server.
E.g. like this:

```js
export function SubjectSelectField(props) {
  const [subjects, setSubjects] = useState([]);
  // Here I use 'loaded' as a check variable when rendering.
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getSubjects = async () => {
      let reqObj = new RequestHandler("/courses/subjects/");
      try{
        const data = await reqObj.sendRequest();
        setSubjects(
          data.map((item) => {
            return <Subject subject={item} />;
          })
        );
        // If the Subjects load properly, set 'loaded' to true.
        setLoaded(true);
      }
      catch(error){
        console.log(`Something went wrong when trying load Subjects from server!`);
        console.error(error);
        // Else we make sure its set to false.
        setLoaded(false);
      }
      
    };
    getSubjects();
  }, []);
  console.log({ subjects });

  // Here, before rendering, we check for the 'loaded' variable
  // to make sure the <select> tag doesn't try to load without
  // the <option> tags. Otherwise, the 'defaultValue' prop won't work.
  if(loaded) return <SelectField init_value={props.init_value} options={subjects} {...props} />;
  return <span>Loading Subject list...</span>;
}
```

Thank you people for trying to look into it at least :)